# IOS handle push notification when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to push UIViewController when notification is clicked and app is closed

following is my code in didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
if application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .background {
        DeeplinkHandler.handleNotification(userNotification: userNotification)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

following is code to handle notification deep link

```
class func handleNotification(userNotification :  UserNotification?){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    var navigationVC = UINavigationController()

    if let tabBarVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let navVC = tabBarVC.viewControllers?[tabBarVC.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
            navigationVC = navVC
        }
        else {
            tabBarVC.selectedIndex = 0
            navigationVC = tabBarVC.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
        }

    }
   // let navigationVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    switch userNotification?.type ?? "" {
    case DeeplinkHandler.NOTIF_TYPE_WEBVIEW:
        let appWebView = AppStrings.appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webPageViewControllerID") as! WebPageViewController
        appWebView.url = userNotification?.url ?? ""
        navigationVC.pushViewController(appWebView, animated: true)
    //case DeeplinkHandler.NOTIF_TYPE_PAGE_ID:
    //case DeeplinkHandler.NOTIF_TYPE_FLIGHT_STATUS:
    default:
        let appWebView = AppStrings.appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationViewControllerID") as! NotificationViewController
        //appWebView.url = userNotification?.url ?? ""
        navigationVC.pushViewController(appWebView, animated: true)

    }
}
```

But notification is click is causing a crash when clicked on notification when app is closed.

How to handle this?

tried following code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
 var notification: [AnyHashable: Any]? = (launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any])
    if let notification = notification {
        print("app received notification from remote\(notification)")
        var userNotification : UserNotification?
        if notification is [String : Any] {
            userNotification = createNSaveNotification(notification)
            DeeplinkHandler.handleNotification(userNotification: userNotification)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("app did not receive notification")
    }
```

this is also crashing app on notification click when app is closed

Comment: You are encouraged to use the [UserNotifications Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) and implement the [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) methods

Comment: “causing a crash“ what crash? Show the crash log. Show the corresponding code.

Comment: since app is closed and launched again it is not showing any log

Comment: Yes, the crash log still exists.

Comment: Also `if application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .inactive` is nonsense.

Comment: device is connected but it is not showing any log

Comment: application.applicationState == .inactive changed this to .background

Comment: also I guess it is crashing because rootviewcontroller is not pushed want to know how to handle pushviewcontroller and navigation controller when notification is opened for app which is closed

Comment: Yes and if you would read the crash log it would tell you that

Comment: how to do that it is not showing log device is connected to my system but it is showing log only if app is running and not showing log is app is closed and notification is clicked

Comment: Use the Devices window.

Comment: And address me as `@matt` or I won’t get the message.

Comment: @matt these are logs Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010296df1c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [4028]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Comment: @matt Terminating because the job-submitter has disconnected.

Comment: Great, so now https://www.google.com/search?q=terminating+because+the+job+submitter+has+disconnected+ios

Comment: Also please note that `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is deprecated. You should not be using this or a deep link to hear about a remote notification.

Answer (score -2):

when app close, you have to check notification in method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey, id> *)launchOptions;
```

and check data in launchOptions

Comment: and question is Swift